# data import from oracle to hdfs with sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

Hi i m getting the error below while trying to import data fro Oracle to HDFS using sqoop.
command used-

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:sys/Welcome123@192.168.41.1:1521:orcl --username tgthr -P --table transactions --columns "tid,accounid,amount" --m 1
```

Error log-

```
    cloudera@cloudera-vm:~$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:sys/Welcome123@192.168.41.1:1521:orcl --username tgthr -P --table transactions --columns "tid,accounid,amount" --m 1
Enter password: 
16/06/27 05:34:51 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
16/06/27 05:34:53 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Io exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
16/06/27 05:34:53 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:935)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:82)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:337)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:423)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:180)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at com.cloudera.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:228)
cloudera@cloudera-vm:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey Its working for me.

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@[ORACLE_SERVER_IP]:1521:orcl --username [ORACLE_USERNAME] --password [ORACLE_PASSWORD] --table [TABLE_NAME] -target-dir 
[/tmp/myoutput]

Note-->Avoid brackets. Its for oracle So for other databases connection string will change.

Also "orcl" is my instance name and 1521 is port in oracle please check it and then go for import.

Example-->

sqoop import --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521:orcl --username user1 --password Password1 --table MYTAB -target-dir /tmp/myoutput/

table name should be in capital letter.